# How to use Retrofit2 with User Search on GitHub

Tags: android, request, github-api, url-parameters, retrofit2

I have this url on GitHub where I can search users that have "Leo" on their username:

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=leo%20in:login

I've tried mapping it using retrofit2 but I just don't understand how.
What I did was:

```
@GET("/search/users?q={login}%20in:login")
getUsers(@Path("login") String login);
```

and just in case:

```
@GET("search/users")
Call<List<User>> getUsers(@Query("login") String login);
```

I can see these two ways are not right, but I just can't figure it out the right way.

I'm also not sure if there's a better way to search users, but I got this one from here: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users

EDITED:

I also tried:

```
@GET("/search/users")
Call<List<User>> getUsers(@QueryMap Map<String, String> login);
```

And on the layer that calls this method, I do:

```
@Override
public void searchUsers(String name) {

    Map<String, String> loginMap = new HashMap<>();
    loginMap.put(name, "in:login");


    Call<List<User>> users = GithubAPI.getInstance().getUsers(loginMap);
    users.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            String s = response.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Still not working :(
And by not working I mean that response.body == null :(

Comment: Look at the QueryMap tag : https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html this will add your param into key and value.

Comment: But what should I put on my Map to use the "in:login"?
    Map map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("login", "leo");
    map.put("in", "login");    

Could you put a code example?

Comment: It should be map.put("in:", "login") but i am not sure .

Comment: It's still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("search/users")
Call<UserList> getUserList(@Query("q") String filter);
```

Try set letter 'q' as key for request

[image]